# The eloquent builder always attached orderby 'id' even after I have different PrimaryKey.How to get it solve?

Tags: laravel, eloquent, laravel-8, laravel-query-builder

I have my primaryKey as `member_id` (not `id` which is by default in a model) for my table `Members`. I have done the necessary changes in the model as follows.

```
class Member extends Model
{
use HasFactory;
public $timestamps = false;
/**
 * The primary key for the model.
 * 
 * @var string
 */
protected $primaryKey = 'member_id';

/**
 * The "type" of the auto-incrementing ID.
 * 
 * @var string
 */
protected $keyType = 'string';
public $incrementing = false;
```

but `Member::query()` always attach `orderby id asc` at the end of the query.
So I get errors for unknown column `id`. I have tried to reorder from my query but in vain as it is always attached at the end of my query.
How can i get the expected result?

Comment: let me see full query what you have done?

Comment: I have tried this scenario and the result was returned correctly, so please provide us with your code and the query that was fired using [laravel/debugbar](https://github.com/barryvdh/laravel-debugbar)

Comment: @JSTECH the query is simply these `Member::query()`. I have no other changes. I got this error `Illuminate \ Database \ QueryException
SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'id' in 'order clause'

select
  *
from
  members
order by
  id asc
limit
  5 offset 0`

Comment: This is not proper query. Try this one `Member::query()->get()`

Comment: If `orderby id asc` is auto attached to your query then there may be attach Global Scope to your `Member` model.

Comment: @JSTECH how to edit this global Scope of a model?

Comment: Check the `booted` method on your model whether it is attach or not.

Comment: if I use `Member::query()->get()` I get this error `App\Http\Livewire\MemberList::datasource(): Return value must be of type Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder, Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection returned`. Actually I am using this `Member::query()` in powergrid package.

Comment: I have not overridden the booted method in my `Model`.

Comment: You didn't paste all code of Member model. So that I can tell you where to edit.

Comment: Try this one `Member::query()->withoutGlobalScopes()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After a long struggle with the code, I hunt down the main reason why it is not working as aspected.And thought to post the solution here so that someone like me do not waste time, in finding whats wrong.
I had used Powergrid DataTable Package [here](https://livewire-powergrid.com) and found this

> By default, PowerGrid uses the field id as your Model’s primary key.
>
> If your model uses a custom primary key, you must configure the property
> $primaryKey in your PowerGrid component.

```
final class MemberList extends PowerGridComponent
{
use ActionButton;

public string $primaryKey = 'members.member_id';

public string $sortField = 'members.member_id';

 public function datasource(): Builder
{
    
    return Member::query()
}
//..
//..
```

Now with this changes in the powergrid datatable file (where I fired the `Member.query()` function, it is working fine now.

Answer (score 0):

I first tried the Veer's solution which initially worked, but then when trying to call ->first() there was an error about querying members.members.member_id.

Then I actually found from our own code a solution inspired by JS Techs answer about disabling Global Scopes. I found that there was actually an overwrite where the id field was added. Changing id -> members.id helped me to make the automatic order by non-ambiguous:

```
/**
 * Sort products by default by id asc
 * Remove default sorting by adding ->withoutGlobalScope(OrderScope::class)
 */
protected static function boot()
{
    parent::boot();
    static::addGlobalScope(new OrderScope('members.id', 'asc'));
}
```